# Is it possible to check gmail using chrome, but not have it display login on screen?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, privacy

I don't like how chrome displays my email address in the top right hand corner when I login to gmail.

Is there a way to not have it do this?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue related to the browser, can you show us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Why is this important for you? Your email address would most likely show up when reading a mail as well (at least chances are there). Is this for some kind of presentation? How about showing your name?

I'm not sure whether this is because I've registered for Google+, but for me it doesn't show my email address up there. Instead it shows my name and a dropdown/profile field/image:

[image: GMail - top right corner shown in Google Chrome]

If this is not what you're refering to, try adding a screenshot showing the bit you're having trouble with or concerns. Just make the full address unreadable.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Google+, as I'm registered too, and it shows my email address.

Comment: I have two Google accounts, one with Google+ and one without. The one with shows my name; the one without, my email address.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. So if you don't want to have your email address up there, register for Google+ (even if you won't touch it ever again) and it's gone. Maybe it's some additional setting? Haven't seen such though.